# Why is hashing algorithm like SHA-256 required in JWT signature?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, jwt

For the signing a JWT, the issuer uses a private key to create the signature of the hash of base64 encoded header and payload.
But the purpose of verifying the authenticity of JWT signature can also be fulfilled by only using base64 encoded contents without hashing them.
What is the significance of using hashing algorithm like SHA-256 in JWT signing process?

I am expecting to understand the purpose of using hashing in JWT signature process. I searched online but could not find the answer

Comment: Hashing is generally performed during signing, i.e. not only in the context of JWTs. Why is this so? See e.g. [Why hash the message before signing it with RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12768)

Comment: Yeah, and that answer also basically invalidates the idea that you don't need to hash due to the space constraints for the various signature algorithms. So it is both impossible, and if the message was small enough, it would still be insecure. Hashing is a configurable requirement of signature algorithms and *is considered an integral part of the algorithm*. Actually, sometimes multiple messages are hashed, the hashes are put in a data structure and then that data structure is signed using another (run of) the hash function (e.g. CMS/PKCS#7 structures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing algorithms like SHA-256 take an input of <2^64 bits and produce an output of 256 bits.

So if we sign the hash instead of signing the raw JWT contents, the signature size will be small.
Hence the purpose of using hashing in JWT is to achieve compression thereby reducing the signature size